What is the difference between "splash" and "dump water out" when bathing my baby?
I am teaching my babies their first words during bath time. What is the difference between "splash" and "dump water out" when bathing my baby?

A person 'splashing about' in the bath sends the water flying by moving their arms and legs, and some of it may end up on the floor (depending on how near the water surface is to the top of the bath). I'm not sure where you found the expression 'dump water out', but it suggests to me deliberately tipping it out of the bath, which I'm sure a baby wouldn't do.

The first is easier to say to a baby and lends itself to reduplication e.g. splish-splash,  the second is not idiomatic and awkward:  "dump the water out" would be an improvement. Do you mean "throw out the water"?

When you make pasta, you dump water out of the pan.

"Splashing" is just flinging a little bit of water around. It may be deliberate or unintentional; a baby would probably do it by flailing their arms or legs around. Children are often told things like, "Don't splash your brother!" or "Don't splash water on the floor!" when playing in the pool, taking a bath, carrying a container full of water, filling a glass from the faucet, etc. As @Mari-Lou A mentions, "splish-splash" is a commonly used phrase in children's books, rhymes, games, etc. as a cute way to represent the sound of water moving around (or, for your vocab word of the day, as an onomatopoeia) .
"Dumping water out" is pouring a lot of water out of a container. I believe that it usually implies that it was done deliberately, as I would feel the need to add "He dumped the water out accidentally" if I wanted to suggest that it was not intentional. It would be difficult to dump water out of most bathtubs that I am familiar with (built-in fixtures), but theoretically possible with a free-standing bathtub, though certainly not by a baby. A baby could scoop up water in a bucket, cup, or other small container and then dump it out of that.
